# Sporadic NoSuchFileException for existing file on Windows

Tags: java, windows, nio

*TL;DR*: I have a test that spawns a new process that reads and writes a file in an endless loop. After a while, my test kills the spawned process again and checks whether the written file was not corrupted.

Sporadically the test fails with a `NoSuchFileException`. However, the file does actually exist: if I check for its existence (i.e., calling `Files.exists(..)`) in the catch block of the `NoSuchFileException` **the file *magically* "reappears" after a few milliseconds**.

### The test code

```
    // 1. create some random file data
    byte[] data = new byte[4096 * 2];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = (byte) random.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        // 2. write random data into file
        File file = tempDir.newFile("temp_" + i);
        Files.write(file.toPath(), data);
        // 3. spawn proccess
        Process process = spawnProcess(file);
        Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(500, 1000));
        // 4. kill process
        process.destroyForcibly();
        assertThat(process.isAlive(), is(false));
        try {
            // 5. make sure file was not corrupted
            assertThat(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()).length, greaterThan(0));
        } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (!Files.exists(file.toPath())) {
                System.out.println("File not visible yet...");
            }
            System.out.println("File reappeared magically after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

### The code of the spawned process

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // 1. path of the file that was created by the test is passed as argument
        Path file = Paths.get(args[0]);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(file);
        while (true) {
            // 2. try to write the file transactionally
            // - write to temp file first and then move it atomically to original file
            Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(file.getFileName().toString(), null);
            Files.copy(file, tempFile, COPY_ATTRIBUTES, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            Files.write(tempFile, data);
            Files.move(tempFile, file, ATOMIC_MOVE, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }}
```

### Output from the catch clause

*File not visible yet...

File not visible yet...

File not visible yet...

[Omitted some lines]

File reappeared magically after: 22ms*

The stack trace of the `NoSuchFileException`:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\STEFAN~1.MOS\AppData\Local\Temp\junit8070411457691609987\temp_2164
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
```

...

Can someone explain how this `NoSuchFileException` can happen? I already disabled the write cache of my disk, however the issue still persists. I use Windows 10 and JDK 1.8.0_102-b14.

Comment: Try using SYNC/DSYNC (see [Synchronized I/O File Integrity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html#integrity)). The while-loop in the spawned process is hammering the file-system in such a way that all kind of I/O optimizations are kicked off by the OS (both Linux and Windows will do this). I'm not surprised this gives some odd behaviour. The (D)SYNC options will tell the OS that it is OK to be slow and wait for disk operations to complete - that should get rid of some of the odd behaviour.

Comment: did you eventually get to the bottom of this issue? i am seeing the same issue and can't find the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\STEFAN~1.MOS\AppData\Local\Temp\junit8070411457691609987\temp_2164
```

you are trying to read a temp file. A temp file has no guarantee of existence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right the temp file could theoretically be deleted - however after some milliseconds the file reappears (see the Output section of my question). Moreover, the issue is reproducible even though the file is created in a none temp folder.